# Android Manifest error: Activities not assignable to android.app.activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So I went to sleep and then when I woke up I opened up my Android project. There is one blaring error all over my Android Manifest file.

All screens in the AndroidManifest show that they are not assignable to 'android.app.activity'

I never had this problem before. Obviously all of my activities are activities and not fragments. (Looking at the answers here, most of it have that kind of error; mistaking fragment for activity)

Also, this Android project has never thrown this kind of error for the past few months.

Right now all of my screens are showing red lines.

Somehow I can run the project just fine even with all those red lines.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Cleaned up the project (Build -> Clean Up)
2. Rebuild the project (Build -> Rebuild)
3. Invalidate caches and restart

I'm running the latest Android Studio.

UPDATE:

Here's my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thispackage.thispackagename">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ScreenOne"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".ScreenTwo"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ScreenThree"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ScreenFour"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ScreenFive"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <!--<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"-->
            <!--android:configChanges=-->
                <!--"keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"-->
            <!--android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"-->
            <!--android:label="@string/app_name" />-->


    </application>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE 2: The following is the screenshot of the error.

[image: error message]

UPDATE 3: When I clicked more, it shows this:

[image: when clicked more]

Comment: can you  share the complete manifest please with error

Comment: @UmarAta just added in my question.

Comment: At which point you are getting error and      you are extending activity or appcompact activity

Comment: @UmarAta I'm extending AppCompatActivity. I get this error when I opened this project.

Comment: Ok , I have few tips 1. Close all opened files in editor 2. Then clean or rebuild project 3. Try to create a new project and check whethe the same error occured or not

Comment: So what's the current status

Comment: @UmarAta I haven't created a new project. Just did no. 1 and 2. Still the same.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot with error

Comment: Actually manifest seems to be fine but what happening when you are running your project

Comment: @UmarAta I tried adding some toast message and it works just fine. I can even generate APK too. Will provide screenshot later. I'm eating right now :)

Comment: Well so much time has passed but you not uploaded the screenshot ,are you eating till now.

Comment: When you click on warning popup more button what it shows

Comment: @UmarAta updated my question with the warning screenshot.

Comment: Ok got it , what context are you using  in xml layout of activities cqn you post anyone xml of activity. May be problem resides in it

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this to clear these types of errors

- Close all opened files in editor
- Then clean or rebuild project
- Try to create a new project and check whether the same error occurred or not
- Invalidate Caches and restart android studio (File Menu -> Invalidate Chaches /Restart)

And in the last if all these not got succeeded then delete **build** folder from your project directory and app directory.

warning - Deleting **build** will delete your previously generated apk too as well as all the downloaded and extracted dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Go to your activity where your error is occurring. There will be an import in the top which included android.app.Activity. Just clear it and reimport by pressing Alt+Enter.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to give full package name for Activity when declaring in manifest. Just Remove your package name from activity declaration.

```
<activity name=".ScreenTwo"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: It's still the same. It does not rectify the error.

Comment: Which class those activities are extending from??

Comment: it extends from AppCompatActivity.

Comment: This is not a an answer, It can be a comment